# Apache Solr: How to index documents having fields which are having hierarchical json object as a value with no defined structure

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am doing poc to use se Solr as a search engine for submitting documents having fields with values as another hierarchical json object. The child objects have no definite structure as I are looking to use Solr to store business events like. Let's suppose below is one business event.

{
"event_id" : "22b2-44ca-66a6-2aad",
"event_type" : "login",
"data": {
"timestamp" : "2023-10-12",
"userid": 1,
.....
}
}

There could be any type of events like download, delete, create, upload etc, where the fields of data keys and values could be any with no defined structure, basically it will capture audit logs.

Can some please suggest how can we do this in solr?
Or maybe do solr is best fit in this case, I have not found any thing similar in Solr.